# Filtrar ultimas 3 avaliações Oracle sql

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

Estou fazendo um relatório e preciso filtrar as 3 ultimas avaliações de fornecedores no caso de esse fornecedor estar com a avaliação negativa na data requisitada no relatório.

Cada avaliação tem várias perguntas e *preciso trazer todas essas perguntas de cada uma das 3 ultimas avaliações de cada fornecedor*.

Segue o que já tenho pronto:

```
 SELECT   forn.cd_fornecedor,
     forn.nm_fornecedor,
     isoa.cd_avaliacao,
     isoa.cd_ranking,
     isoa.vl_nota,
     isoa.vl_media,
     isoa.dt_avaliacao,
     isor.cd_resposta,
     isor.cd_itpergunta,
     isoi.cd_pergunta,
     isoi.ds_itpergunta,
     isop.ds_pergunta

   FROM fornecedor forn,
        iso_avaliacao isoa,
        iso_resposta isor,
        iso_itpergunta isoi,
        iso_pergunta isop

  WHERE forn.cd_fornecedor = isoa.cd_fornecedor
    AND isoa.cd_avaliacao = isor.cd_avaliacao
    AND isor.cd_itpergunta = isoi.cd_itpergunta
    AND isoi.cd_pergunta = isop.cd_pergunta
    --AND isoa.cd_ranking IN (1, 7)
    AND forn.cd_fornecedor in (select isoa2.cd_fornecedor 
                                from iso_avaliacao isoa2
                                where isoa2.dt_avaliacao between to_date('01/01/2016') and to_date('20/01/2016')
                                        and isoa2.cd_ranking in (1,7)
                                        /*and isoa2.cd_avaliacao in (select isoa3.cd_avaliacao
                                                                        from iso_avaliacao isoa3
                                                                        where )*/
                                        )

 --AND FORN.CD_FORNECEDOR = 4272 
 --AND ISOP.CD_PERGUNTA > 6 
 --AND ISOI.DS_ITPERGUNTA = 'NAO' 

ORDER BY forn.nm_fornecedor, isoa.cd_avaliacao desc,   isoa.dt_avaliacao;
```

Comment: Duas soluções me ocorrem , usar uma subquery com order by e testando runnum , algo assim : select * from (select * from tabela order by data desc) where rownum < 4   ou usar as Analytic Functions do Rrcle ( http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174 ) usando as funções RANK ou DENSE_RANK

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi, quer que essa subquerie retorne apenas os 3 primeiros. Então tem de recorrer ao rownum. (Se fosse Oracle12c, existe agora uma forma mais eficaz).
ex:

```
(select * from 
     (select isoa2.cd_fornecedor 
       from iso_avaliacao isoa2
      where isoa2.dt_avaliacao between to_date('01/01/2016') and  to_date('20/01/2016')
          and isoa2.cd_ranking in (1,7))
where rownum<=3)
```